# ubuntu bookmarks

Tags: script, ubuntu, backup

I want to backup my ubuntu bookmarks (not browser bookmarks, but the ones in the places pane in nautilus). However, I can't find any application that does it already or any info on where bookmarks are stored and how. Can anybody tell me a way in which this can be done?

Any suggestions about a script is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.gtk-bookmarks` 
Notice that this is a file, not a folder. Additionally, it's a **hidden** file so you won't see it in your file manager by default.

Comment: That folder is not present in my home.

Comment: It's a file, and not a folder. And it's a hidden file (because it's got a leading dot), just adjust your settings in nautilus or whatever to see hidden files.

Comment: If you are using the Gnome desktop (if you're not sure, then you are using it - it's default in Ubuntu), then it reads the bookmarks from there (and from nowhere else). Note that Linux treats filenames starting with a dot `.` as hidden - you'll need to press Ctrl+H in Nautilus (file explorer) to show them.